# asp.net file download issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, io

I am downloading files from server to client machine using below code but when the file saves it saves with full path name followed by extension(Ex:Images/24/12/green.png) but i want to store only file name(green.png) in the client machine.how can it be done

```
string imagePath = String.Format("~/Images/{0}/{1}", item.Value,item.Text);
                try
                {

                    System.Net.WebClient req = new System.Net.WebClient();
                    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                    response.Clear();
                    response.ClearContent();
                    response.ClearHeaders();
                    response.Buffer = true;
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+ imagePath + "\"");
                    //byte[] data = req.DownloadData(imagePath);
                    //response.BinaryWrite(data);
                    response.TransmitFile(imagePath);
                    response.End();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only use the image name instead of the whole path in the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(imagePath);
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment;filename=\""+ fileName + "\"");
```

You have given the file name as the file and the server side path to it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the missing info.